# Is the blackbody distribution the maximally radiative spectral distribution at fixed temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

A blackbody at temperature $T$ will radiate at a rate proportional to $\sigma T^4$. In general, however, most substances are not perfect blackbodies, and in e.g. the case of a gas made of a single element the spectrum at which the substance emits will be constrained to a few fixed lines. My question is: is it always the case that if the emission spectrum of some substance differs from that of a blackbody, the radiation rate will be lower? This strikes me as intuitively sensible (after all, if there was an "optimal" spectral profile for radiating energy, what would it be other than the blackbody spectrum?), but is it true?

Comment: A body that is not black also does not absorb at all the frequencies.

Comment: Is this another way to ask your question: Is it possible to emit more than what's being absorbed?

Comment: @Newbie I'm not entirely sure! On the one hand it seems like it should be the case that e.g. a monoatomic gas kept in contact with a blackbody should emit precisely the same amount of energy that it receives from the blackbody, which would only be a subset of the energy radiated by the blackbody. But on the other hand, what's to stop one from creating a substance with a contrived density of states that might similarly emit more radiation than the blackbody would absorb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later and I'm back to answer this question, in case anyone has a similar curiosity.

The answer is that any sort of body will, at an intuitive level, have some "density of states" for holding EM waves. The argument that leads to blackbody radiation at any specific wavelength is simply that the amount of radiation is directly proportional to the occupancy of these degrees of freedom at that wavelength in the body. An idealized blackbody such as e.g. a vacuum radiation bath is simply a body where every single such degree of freedom, as permitted by the quantum mechanics of radiation, is available. One cannot create a hypothetical body with more degrees of freedom than a blackbody for EM waves because there simply are not more degrees of freedom available. Thus the blackbody must be the maximally radiative body at a fixed temperature.